# TypeError: b is undefined in jquery.validate.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I got TypeError: b is undefined in my web app. I included latest version jquery and i check same id is exist.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('#instantquotebtn').on('click', function() {


    if($("#instantquotefrm").validate()){    

        alert("Validation OK");
    }

});

});
```

Comment: Where is the HTML markup for this?

Comment: The `.validate()` method is only used for initializing the plugin, not for triggering validation.  You would never put `.validate()` inside of a `click` handler or a conditional statement.  It makes no sense here.  Once properly initialized, the click is *automatically* captured and the form is validated.  You also **must** have a unique `name` attribute on all form elements being validated.